# Select2 add class to select2-container when no results

Tags: jquery-select2

I would like to be able to add class to the select2-container div when their is no results. Is this possible because there doesn't seem to have any way to catch an even when there is no results.

Thanks!

Comment: When my ajax comes back empty, I add one option that says no options available then disable the select box

Answer (score 0):

I would add the class first and then remove it on the `change` event.

```
$('.nameOfContainer').on('select2:change', function (evt) {
   $(this).removeClass('noResults');
});
```